# Spectrum Problem for Higher-Order Logic

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

**Definitions.**  Given a sentence $\varphi$ of $n$th-order logic, we define the spectrum of $\varphi$ to be the set of cardinalities of finite structures that satisfy $\varphi$. A set $X\subseteq\mathbb N$ is said to be an $n$th-order spectrum if there is an $n$th-order sentence whose spectrum is $X$. Given any positive integer $n$, let $S_n$ be the set of all $n$th-order spectra. An $\omega$-order spectrum is an element of the set $S_{\omega}:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}S_n$.

**Questions.**

1. Clearly, $S_n\subseteq S_{n+1}$ for each positive integer $n$. One knows that $S_1\subsetneq S_2$ (J. H. Bennett, *On spectra*, 1962).

   > Do we have $S_n\subsetneq S_{n+1}$ for each positive integer $n$?
2. One does not know if the complement of a first-order spectrum is also a first-order spectrum. That is why I wonder:

   > Is the complement of a second-order spectrum always a second-order spectrum? Is the complement of a third-order spectrum always a third-order spectrum? ...
3. For each positive integer $n$, every element of $S_n$ is decidable. But we can always construct a decidable set $D_n$ which is not in $S_n$: We simply construct the diagonal set $D_n$ such that $m \in D_n$ if and only if $m$ is not in the $m$th $n$th-order spectrum. ([source](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-fagin/genspec.pdf), page 2)

   > Is $D_n$ always an element of $S_{n+1}$? Is $D_n$ always an element of some $S_p$, where $p>n$?
4. > Is the complement of an $\omega$-order spectrum always an $\omega$-order spectrum?

Comment: For your version of second-order and higher-order logic, do we quantify just over unary predicates, or can we also quantify over binary predicates, trinary and so on?

Comment: I would say that we can also quantify over binary predicates, trinary and so on. However, I am also interested in anwers to my questions where "second-order" is interpreted as "monadic second-order".

Comment: It is well known that $S_1=\mathrm{NE}$. Now, it would require some effort to work it out, but I am pretty confident this should generalize to $S_k=\mathrm{NTIME}(2_k^n)$, where $2_0^n=n$, $2_{k+1}^n=2^{2_k^n}$. If true, this would imply that $S_k\subsetneq S_{k+1}$ for all $k$, that the closure of $S_k$ under complement is highly unlikely, but open (and harder and harder to disprove as $k$ gets larger), and that $S_\omega$ *is* closed under complement as $\mathrm{co}S_k\subseteq S_{k+1}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Thanks! Are you about to put some effort into working out your idea?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: If you post a proof or a proof sketch of the formula $S_k=\mathrm{NTIME}(2_k^n)$, then I will accept this as an answer, since it would provide responses to the questions 1, 2 and 4 (question number 3 is very vague, because I did not define how to number the spectra).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Hello? Are you ignoring me? http://www.allmystery.de/i/t88c40e_Are-you-ignoring-my-backlinks.png?bc

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m busy. Maybe I will have time to return to this later, but not at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

One can answer questions about higher-order spectra by characterizing $S_d$ as certain complexity classes, based on similar characterizations for classes of structures *definable* by fragments of higher-order logic.

Let me first recall how things work for the base case (first-order logic, i.e., $S_1$). Let $\phi$ be an FO sentence in a finite relational signature $\sigma=\{R_1,\dots,R_k\}$. If we reconsider each $R_i$ as a second-order variable, we can quantify them away in second-order logic to get the $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence
$$\Phi=\exists R_1\dots\exists R_k\,\phi(R_1,\dots,R_k)$$
in the empty signature with the property
$$\exists M\,(|M|=n\land M\vDash\phi)\iff M_n\vDash\Phi,$$
where $M_n$ denotes the $n$-element model with no extra structure. Conversely, every $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence in the empty language is of the form $\Phi$ for some first-order $\phi$. Thus, FO spectra are exactly sets of the form
$$\{n\in\mathbb N:M_n\vDash\Phi\}$$
for $\Sigma^1_1$ sentences $\Phi$ in the empty signature.

Now, Fagin's theorem states

> **Theorem:** Let $\sigma$ be a finite signature. A class of finite $\sigma$-structures is definable by a $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence iff it is recognizable in NP.

Applying this to empty $\sigma$, we see that FO spectra are sets of the form
$$\{n\in\mathbb N:M_n\in L\},\qquad L\in\mathrm{NP}.$$
Observe that $M_n$ is more-or-less just the unary encoding of $n$ itself. Since conversion from the usual binary representation to unary blows up the input exponentially, it is easy to see that this implies
$$S_1=\mathrm{NE}:=\mathrm{NTime}(2^{O(n)}).$$

We can generalize this to higher-order logic, but first we have to decide what exactly *is* higher-order logic. There are at least two important choices to be made:

1. What things can appear in the signature in $d$-th order logic? In FO, we have just predicates $R(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ where $x_i$ are first-order entities. Such predicates are effectively the same as free *second-order* variables. There are two obvious ways how to generalize this to $d$-th order logic:

   a) The signature can contain predicates $R(X_1,\dots,X_k)$, where $X_i$ are variables of any type allowed in the logic; that is, order $d$ or lower. This makes $R$ effectively a free variable of order at most $d+1$.

   I will denote spectra for this form of $d$-th order logic $S_d^+$.

   b) The signature can only contain predicates $R(x_1,\dots,x_k)$, where $x_i$ are first-order. That is, it is just an FO signature.

   I will denote spectra for this form of $n$th order logic $S_d^-$.
2. Do the higer-order variables have arbitrary arity, or only unary (monadic)? I will consider the former as default ($S_d^+$, $S_d^-$), and denote the spectra for the latter as $MS_d^+$, $MS_d^-$.

Second, we need an analogue of Fagin’s theorem. The following natural generalization is given in Kołodziejczyk [1]. Let me define the iterated exponential function $2_0^n=n$, $2_{d+1}^n=2^{2_d^n}$.

> **Theorem:** Let $\sigma$ be a finite FO signature, $d\ge2$, and $m,k\ge1$. A set of finite $\sigma$-structures is definable by a $\Sigma^d_m$ sentence (that’s $(d+1)$-th order!) using only higher-order variables of arity $\le k$ if and only if it is recognizable in $\Sigma_m\text{-Time}(2_{d-1}^{O(n^k)})$.

Here, $\Sigma_m\text{-Time}(f(n))$ is the class of languages recognizable by an alternating Turing machine in time $f(n)$ with $m-1$ alternations, starting in an existential state.

The case of $\Sigma^1_m$ is more tricky, but as long as we do not restrict the arity, we still have that $\Sigma^1_m$-definable = recognizable in $\Sigma_m\text{-Time}(2_0^{n^{O(1)}})=\Sigma_m^P$.

By the same argument as when going from Fagin’s theorem to characterization of $S_1$, we obtain:

> **Theorem:** Let $d\ge2$.
>
> - $S_d^+=\mathrm{NTime}(2_d^{O(n)})$
> - $S_d^-=\mathrm{AltTime}(O(1),2_{d-1}^{O(n)})$
> - $\mathrm{NTime}(2_d^{n+O(1)})\subseteq MS_d^+\subseteq S_d^+=\mathrm{NTime}(2_d^{O(n)})$
> - $MS_d^-=\mathrm{AltTime}(O(1),2_{d-1}^{n+O(1)})$ for $d\ge3$; $\mathrm{NE}\cup\mathrm{AltTime}(O(1),O(2^n))\subseteq MS_2^-\subseteq S_2^-=\mathrm{EH}$
> - $S_\omega=\mathrm{ELEMENTARY}$, where $S_\omega:=\bigcup_dS_d^+=\bigcup_dS_d^-=\bigcup_dMS_d^+=\bigcup_dMS_d^-$.

Here, $\mathrm{AltTime}(f(n),g(n))$ denotes languages recognizable by an alternating TM with $f(n)$ alternations in time $g(n)$; in particular, $\mathrm{AltTime}(O(1),g(n))=\bigcup_m\Sigma_m\text{-Time}(g(n))$.

An exact characterization of the $MS$ classes gets messy because of the fact that the extra existential quantifiers we get by quantifying away the nonlogical symbols in the sentence do *not* have bounded arity unlike the rest. However, the above is sufficient for our purposes.

Now, we can answer the questions in turn.

Q1: Using standard variants of the nondeterministic time-hierarchy theorem, we have
$$\begin{gather*}
S_1\subsetneq S_2^+\subsetneq S_3^+\subsetneq S_4^+\subsetneq\cdots\\
S_1\subsetneq MS_2^+\subsetneq MS_3^+\subsetneq MS_4^+\subsetneq\cdots\\
S_1\subseteq S_2^-\subsetneq S_3^-\subsetneq S_4^-\subsetneq\cdots\\
S_1\subseteq MS_2^-\subsetneq MS_3^-\subsetneq MS_4^-\subsetneq\cdots
\end{gather*}$$

The inclusions $S_1\subseteq MS_2^-$ and $S_1\subseteq S_2^-$ are also conjecturally strict. Despite the imprecision in our characterization of $MS_2^-$, the closure properties of $\mathrm{NE}$ ensure
$$S_1=MS_2^-\iff S_1=S_2^-\iff \mathrm{NE=EH}.$$
It is generally assumed that $\mathrm{NE\ne EH}$, but as this implies $\mathrm{NP\ne coNP}$, it remains a difficult open problem.

Q2: The classes $S_d^-$ for $d\ge2$, and $MS_d^-$ for $d\ge 3$ are closed under complement. Under unproven complexity-theoretic assumptions, $S_1$, $S_d^+$, and $MS_d^+$ are not closed under complement, but this is at least as hard to prove as $\mathrm{NP\ne coNP}$. The remaining case is $MS_2^-$; based on the asymmetry in its characterization, I’d think this might also *not* be closed under complement, but I don’t have a generally accepted complexity assumption to support it.

Q3: This depends wildly on how you define $D_n$, however, diagonalization using a natural and reasonably efficient enumeration of sentences should indeed give $D_n\subseteq S_{n+1}$, with appropriate superscripts and modifiers.

Q4: Yes.

**Reference:**

[1] Leszek A. Kołodziejczyk, *Truth definitions in finite models*, Journal of Symbolic Logic 69 (2004), no. 1, pp. 183–200. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30041718), [preprint](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~lak/FM-Truth.pdf)

Comment: I should perhaps stress that the closure under complement of $S_d^-$ and $S_\omega$ is immediate (quantify nonlogical symbols away, and negate the resulting sentence). It does not need the detour via computational complexity.